# Database size not reduced after compressing tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, size, compression

Using Data Compression, my table size was reduced from 1770 MB to 250 MB, but the database size was not reduced. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also shrink a database and shrink database files. See MS:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Erik

Comment: You should beware when shrinking database files, it affects performance negatively - see http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-930-data-file-shrink-does-not-affect-performance/